# What is the best glMatrixMode() for using GLM?

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml, mingw32, glm-math

my next question(or problem) in line is that when i load a model with glm, im able to see through parts of the model for example: if there were two mountains one in front of the other, i could see through the nearer mountain.

i would show a picture but it wouldnt be understandable since the texture doesnt work.

heres that problem here:

[image]

OLDER STUFF:vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv

all im wondering is: what is the best Matrix mode for using glm?

i have been used to GL_PROJECTION but its giving me too many problems when loading my model

and with GL_MODELVIEW im not able to move the camera back

i am also wondering: if i use GL_MODELVIEW, then how can i move the "camera" in the scene? is there a way to maybe setup one since ima have to eventually?

EDIT: alright heres some code to give you guys some kind of vision:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <vector>
#include <glm/glm.h>
#include <glm/glmint.h>
#include "Item.hpp"
#include "Player.hpp"

///GOLD WAVE
using namespace std;
///GLOBAL VARIABLES
vector<sf::Sprite> SpriteList;
vector<GLMmodel*> ModelList;
vector<GLuint> _texture;
vector<Item*> DefItemList;
Player *pPlayer=new Player();

sf::RenderWindow GameWind(sf::VideoMode(800,600,32),"Carperon Game Window",sf::Style::Titlebar);
sf::View GameView(sf::FloatRect(0,0,25,18.75));//65x45 and 8x  0,0,65,45

///PROTOTYPE FUNCTIONS
void SFMLcreate();
void SFMLdraw();
void GLMcreate();
void GLdraw();
GLuint LoadTexture();
void GLiniti();
void ITEMdefault();
///////////////////////////////////STOP PROTOTYPES//////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////FUNCTIONS//////////////////////////////////
int main()
{
    GLiniti();
    SFMLcreate();
    GLMcreate();
    ITEMdefault();
    sf::Event EventMain;
    vector<sf::Sprite> ShowingBag;
    sf::Image isbItem[45],iseItem[6];
    sf::Sprite sbItem[45],seItem[6];
    int BagSlotX[45] {0,15,30,0,15,30,0,15,30,0,15,30,0,15,30,0,15,30,0,15,30,0,15,30,0,15,30,0,15,30,0,15,30,0,15,30,0,15,30,0,15,30,0,15,30};
    int BagSlotY[45] {0,0,0,15,15,15,30,30,30,0,0,0,15,15,15,30,30,30,0,0,0,15,15,15,30,30,30,0,0,0,15,15,15,30,30,30,0,0,0,15,15,15,30,30,30};
    int EquipSlotY[6] {0,15,30,0,15,30};
    bool BagUpdate = true;
    int click = 0;
    ///MAIN PLAYER
    pPlayer->PlayerCreate("Molma");
    pPlayer->EquipFill(DefItemList[0]);

    pPlayer->AddItem(DefItemList[1]);
    pPlayer->AddItem(DefItemList[2]);
    pPlayer->AddItem(DefItemList[3]);
    pPlayer->AddItem(DefItemList[4]);

    while(GameWind.IsOpened())
    {
        while(GameWind.GetEvent(EventMain))
        {
            //If its closed
            if(EventMain.Type==sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                //Close the whole thing!
                //GameWind.Close();
                GameWind.Close();
            }
        }
        float MouseX = (GameWind.GetInput().GetMouseX()/32.f);
        float MouseY = (GameWind.GetInput().GetMouseY()/32.f);
        if(GameWind.GetInput().IsKeyDown(sf::Key::Escape))
        {
            GameWind.Close();
            //GameWind.Close();
        }
/////////////////////////////BEGIN INPUT/////////////////////////////////////////////////
        if(GameWind.GetInput().IsKeyDown(sf::Key::Return))
        {
            pPlayer->RandHealth();
            BagUpdate = true;

        }
        if(GameWind.GetInput().IsKeyDown(sf::Key::Z))
        {
            pPlayer->GetHit();
        }

        if(GameWind.GetInput().IsMouseButtonDown(sf::Mouse::Right)&&click<=0)
        {
            for(int a=0;a<pPlayer->Bag.size();++a)
            {
                if(MouseX>((17.f+(BagSlotX[a]))/16.f)&&MouseX<(((32.f+(BagSlotX[a]))/16.f))&&MouseY>((60.f+(BagSlotY[a]))/16.f)&&MouseY<(((75.f+(BagSlotY[a]))/16.f)))
                {
                    pPlayer->ItemUse(pPlayer->Bag[a],a);
                    BagUpdate = true;
                    click=20;
                        //cout << "Item used!" << endl;
                }
            }
            for(int b=0;b<6;++b)
            {
                if(MouseX>2.f/16.f&&MouseX<17.f/16.f&&MouseY>((60.f+(EquipSlotY[b]))/16.f)&&MouseY<((75.f+(EquipSlotY[b]))/16.f)&&pPlayer->EqSpot[b]->get_Type()!="Blank Spot")
                {
                    pPlayer->Unequip(pPlayer->EqSpot[b],DefItemList[0],b);
                    BagUpdate = true;
                    click=20;
                }
            }
        }
///////////////////////////////END INPUT/////////////////////////////////////////////////

//////////////////////////////AUTO FUNCTIONS//////////////////////////////////////////////

        pPlayer->Guarding();
        pPlayer->HitTiming();
        if(BagUpdate)
        {
            for(int a=0;a<pPlayer->Bag.size();++a)
            {
                isbItem[a].LoadFromFile("Graphics/Items.png");
                sbItem[a].SetImage(isbItem[a]);
                sbItem[a].SetPosition(((17.f+(BagSlotX[a]))/16.f),((60.f+(BagSlotY[a]))/16.f));
            }
            for(int b=0;b<6;++b)
            {
                    iseItem[b].LoadFromFile("Graphics/Items.png");
                    seItem[b].SetImage(iseItem[b]);
                    seItem[b].SetPosition(2.f/16.f,((60.f+(EquipSlotY[b]))/16.f));
            }
            BagUpdate=false;
        }
        if(click>0)
        {
            click-=1;
        }

        SpriteList[22].SetPosition(MouseX,MouseY);

        GameWind.SetView(GameView);
        GLdraw();
        SFMLdraw();

        for(int a=((pPlayer->get_BagShow())*9);a<((pPlayer->get_BagShow()*9)+9);++a)//18-27=A
        {
            if(a<pPlayer->Bag.size())
            {

            sbItem[a].Resize(15.f/16.f,15.f/16.f);
            sbItem[a].SetSubRect(sf::IntRect((pPlayer->Bag[a]->get_Index()*15),0,((pPlayer->Bag[a]->get_Index()*15)+15),15));
            GameWind.Draw(sbItem[a]);
            //cout << "Items Drawn! Position: " << BagSlotX[a] << "," << BagSlotY[a] << "Item: " << a << endl;
                //image pos resize subrect
            }
        }
        for(int b=((pPlayer->get_EquipShow())*3);b<((pPlayer->get_EquipShow()*3)+3);++b)
        {

                seItem[b].Resize(15.f/16.f,15.f/16.f);
                seItem[b].SetSubRect(sf::IntRect((pPlayer->EqSpot[b]->get_Index()*15),0,((pPlayer->EqSpot[b]->get_Index()*15)+15),15));
                GameWind.Draw(seItem[b]);

        }

        GameWind.Draw(SpriteList[16]);
        GameWind.Draw(SpriteList[20]);
        GameWind.Draw(SpriteList[21]);
        GameWind.Draw(SpriteList[22]);
        GameWind.Display();
        GameWind.SetFramerateLimit(60);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}



void SFMLcreate()
{
    sf::Image iStatBack,iStatWindow,ipHealth,ipEnergy,ipStr,ipDex,ipInt,ipEnd,ipCrit,ipSwd,ipAxe,ipBow,ipStar,ipWand,ipStaff,ipBag,ipEquip,ipSkills,ipNumHP,ipNumEP,ipGuard,ipRank,ipRankXP,iCursor;
    sf::Sprite StatBack,StatWindow,pHealth,pEnergy,pStr,pDex,pInt,pEnd,pCrit,pSwd,pAxe,pBow,pStar,pWand,pStaff,pBag,pEquip,pSkills,pNumHP,pNumEP,pGuard,pRank,pRankXP,Cursor;
    sf::Font MainFont;

    //LoadFromFile
    iStatBack.LoadFromFile("Graphics/Player Stats/Stats Back.png");
    iStatWindow.LoadFromFile("Graphics/Player Stats/StatWindow2.png");
    ipHealth.LoadFromFile("Graphics/Player Stats/Health.png");
    ipEnergy.LoadFromFile("Graphics/Player Stats/Energy.png");
    ipStr.LoadFromFile("Graphics/Player Stats/Strength.png");
    ipDex.LoadFromFile("Graphics/Player Stats/Dexterity.png");
    ipInt.LoadFromFile("Graphics/Player Stats/Intellegence.png");
    ipEnd.LoadFromFile("Graphics/Player Stats/Endurance.png");
    ipCrit.LoadFromFile("Graphics/Player Stats/Critical.png");
    ipSwd.LoadFromFile("Graphics/Player Stats/Sword Mast.png");
    ipAxe.LoadFromFile("Graphics/Player Stats/Axe Mast.png");
    ipBow.LoadFromFile("Graphics/Player Stats/Bow Mast.png");
    ipStar.LoadFromFile("Graphics/Player Stats/Star Mast.png");
    ipWand.LoadFromFile("Graphics/Player Stats/Wand Mast.png");
    ipStaff.LoadFromFile("Graphics/Player Stats/Staff Mast.png");
    ipBag.LoadFromFile("Graphics/Player Stats/Bag.png");
    ipEquip.LoadFromFile("Graphics/Player Stats/Bag.png");
    ipSkills.LoadFromFile("Graphics/Player Stats/Skill.png");
    ipNumHP.LoadFromFile("Graphics/Player Stats/Number HE.png");
    ipNumEP.LoadFromFile("Graphics/Player Stats/Number HE.png");
    ipGuard.LoadFromFile("Graphics/Player Stats/Guard.png");
    ipRank.LoadFromFile("Graphics/Player Stats/Rank.png");
    ipRankXP.LoadFromFile("Graphics/Player Stats/RankXP.png");
    iCursor.LoadFromFile("Graphics/Cursor.png");

    //SetSmooth()
    ipStr.SetSmooth(false);
    ipDex.SetSmooth(false);
    ipInt.SetSmooth(false);
    ipEnd.SetSmooth(false);
    ipCrit.SetSmooth(false);
    ipSwd.SetSmooth(false);
    ipAxe.SetSmooth(false);
    ipBow.SetSmooth(false);
    ipStar.SetSmooth(false);
    ipWand.SetSmooth(false);
    ipStaff.SetSmooth(false);
    ipSkills.SetSmooth(false);
    ipHealth.SetSmooth(false);
    ipEnergy.SetSmooth(false);
    ipGuard.SetSmooth(false);
    ipNumHP.SetSmooth(false);
    ipNumEP.SetSmooth(false);
    ipRankXP.SetSmooth(false);
    ipRank.SetSmooth(false);
    //SetImage!!
    StatBack.SetImage(iStatBack);
    StatWindow.SetImage(iStatWindow);
    pHealth.SetImage(ipHealth);
    pEnergy.SetImage(ipEnergy);
    pStr.SetImage(ipStr);
    pDex.SetImage(ipDex);
    pInt.SetImage(ipInt);
    pEnd.SetImage(ipEnd);
    pCrit.SetImage(ipCrit);
    pSwd.SetImage(ipSwd);
    pAxe.SetImage(ipAxe);
    pBow.SetImage(ipBow);
    pStar.SetImage(ipStar);
    pWand.SetImage(ipWand);
    pStaff.SetImage(ipStaff);
    pBag.SetImage(ipBag);
    pEquip.SetImage(ipEquip);
    pSkills.SetImage(ipSkills);
    pNumHP.SetImage(ipNumHP);
    pNumEP.SetImage(ipNumEP);
    pGuard.SetImage(ipGuard);
    pRank.SetImage(ipRank);
    pRankXP.SetImage(ipRankXP);
    Cursor.SetImage(iCursor);
    //SetPosition(x,y)!!
    StatBack.SetPosition(0,0);
    StatWindow.SetPosition(-5.f/16.f,-5.f/16.f);
    pHealth.SetPosition(5.f/16.f,23.25f/16.f);
    pEnergy.SetPosition(5.f/16.f,31.5f/16.f);
    pStr.SetPosition(59.f/16.f,23.f/16.f);
    pDex.SetPosition(59.f/16.f,35.f/16.f);
    pInt.SetPosition(59.f/16.f,47.f/16.f);
    pEnd.SetPosition(3.f/16.f,37.f/16.f);
    pCrit.SetPosition(32.f/16.f,37.f/16.f);
    pSwd.SetPosition(63.f/16.f,21.f/16.f);
    pAxe.SetPosition(63.f/16.f,29.f/16.f);
    pBow.SetPosition(63.f/16.f,33.f/16.f);
    pStar.SetPosition(63.f/16.f,41.f/16.f);
    pWand.SetPosition(63.f/16.f,45.f/16.f);
    pStaff.SetPosition(63.f/16.f,53.f/16.f);
    pBag.SetPosition(2.f/16.f,60.f/16.f);
    pEquip.SetPosition(2.f/16.f,60.f/16.f);
    pSkills.SetPosition(71.f/16.f,61.f/16.f);
    pNumHP.SetPosition(4.f/16.f,22.f/16.f);
    pNumEP.SetPosition(4.f/16.f,30.f/16.f);
    pGuard.SetPosition(4.f/16.f,22.5f/16.f);
    pRank.SetPosition(41.5f/16.f,25.f/16.f);
    pRankXP.SetPosition(39.5f/16.f,23.f/16.f);

    //VECTOR STORE
    SpriteList.push_back(StatWindow);
    SpriteList.push_back(pHealth);
    SpriteList.push_back(pEnergy);
    SpriteList.push_back(pStr);
    SpriteList.push_back(pDex);
    SpriteList.push_back(pInt);
    SpriteList.push_back(pEnd);
    SpriteList.push_back(pCrit);
    SpriteList.push_back(pSwd);
    SpriteList.push_back(pAxe);
    SpriteList.push_back(pBow);
    SpriteList.push_back(pStar);
    SpriteList.push_back(pWand);
    SpriteList.push_back(pStaff);
    SpriteList.push_back(pBag);
    SpriteList.push_back(pEquip);
    SpriteList.push_back(pSkills);
    SpriteList.push_back(pNumHP);
    SpriteList.push_back(pNumEP);
    SpriteList.push_back(pGuard);
    SpriteList.push_back(pRank);
    SpriteList.push_back(pRankXP);
    SpriteList.push_back(Cursor);


}


void SFMLdraw()
{
//////////////////////////////STAT RESIZE/SUBRECT///////////////////////////////////////
        SpriteList[1].SetSubRect(sf::IntRect(0,0,120,12)); //30,3
        SpriteList[2].SetSubRect(sf::IntRect(0,0,120,12)); //30,3
        SpriteList[3].SetSubRect(sf::IntRect(pPlayer->get_Str()*28,0,(pPlayer->get_Str()*28)+28,7)); //28,7
        SpriteList[4].SetSubRect(sf::IntRect(pPlayer->get_Dex()*28,0,(pPlayer->get_Dex()*28)+28,7)); //28,7
        SpriteList[5].SetSubRect(sf::IntRect(pPlayer->get_Int()*28,0,(pPlayer->get_Int()*28)+28,7)); //28,7
        SpriteList[6].SetSubRect(sf::IntRect(pPlayer->get_End()*28,0,(pPlayer->get_End()*28)+28,7)); //28,7
        SpriteList[7].SetSubRect(sf::IntRect(pPlayer->get_Crit()*28,0,(pPlayer->get_Crit()*28)+28,7)); //28,7
        SpriteList[8].SetSubRect(sf::IntRect(pPlayer->get_Sword()*18,0,(pPlayer->get_Sword()*18)+18,3)); //18,3
        SpriteList[9].SetSubRect(sf::IntRect(pPlayer->get_Axe()*18,0,(pPlayer->get_Axe()*18)+18,3)); //18,3
        SpriteList[10].SetSubRect(sf::IntRect(pPlayer->get_Bow()*18,0,(pPlayer->get_Bow()*18)+18,3)); //18,3
        SpriteList[11].SetSubRect(sf::IntRect(pPlayer->get_Star()*18,0,(pPlayer->get_Star()*18)+18,3)); //18,3
        SpriteList[12].SetSubRect(sf::IntRect(pPlayer->get_Wand()*18,0,(pPlayer->get_Wand()*18)+18,3)); //18,3
        SpriteList[13].SetSubRect(sf::IntRect(pPlayer->get_Staff()*18,0,(pPlayer->get_Staff()*18)+18,3)); //18,3
        SpriteList[14].SetSubRect(sf::IntRect((pPlayer->get_BagShow()*60)+120,0,(pPlayer->get_BagShow()*60)+180,48));
        SpriteList[15].SetSubRect(sf::IntRect(pPlayer->get_EquipShow()*60,0,(pPlayer->get_EquipShow()*60)+60,48));
        SpriteList[16].SetSubRect(sf::IntRect(pPlayer->get_SkillShow()*30,0,(pPlayer->get_SkillShow()*30)+30,64));
        SpriteList[17].SetSubRect(sf::IntRect(pPlayer->get_Health()*7,0,(pPlayer->get_Health()*7)+7,5));
        SpriteList[18].SetSubRect(sf::IntRect(pPlayer->get_Energy()*7,0,(pPlayer->get_Energy()*7)+7,5));
        SpriteList[19].SetSubRect(sf::IntRect(0,0,128,20));
        SpriteList[20].SetSubRect(sf::IntRect(pPlayer->get_Rank()*14,0,(pPlayer->get_Rank()*14)+14,6));//10
        SpriteList[21].SetSubRect(sf::IntRect(pPlayer->get_tRankXPN()*18,0,(pPlayer->get_tRankXPN()*18)+18,10));//16

/////////////////////RESIZE PART
        SpriteList[0].Resize(410.f/16.f,310.f/16.f);
        SpriteList[1].Resize(pPlayer->get_tHealth()/64.f,12.f/64.f);
        SpriteList[2].Resize(pPlayer->get_tEnergy()/64.f,12.f/64.f);
        SpriteList[3].Resize(28.f/16.f,7.f/16.f);
        SpriteList[4].Resize(28.f/16.f,7.f/16.f);
        SpriteList[5].Resize(28.f/16.f,7.f/16.f);
        SpriteList[6].Resize(28.f/16.f,7.f/16.f);
        SpriteList[7].Resize(28.f/16.f,7.f/16.f);
        SpriteList[8].Resize(18.f/16.f,3.f/16.f);
        SpriteList[9].Resize(18.f/16.f,3.f/16.f);
        SpriteList[10].Resize(18.f/16.f,3.f/16.f);
        SpriteList[11].Resize(18.f/16.f,3.f/16.f);
        SpriteList[12].Resize(18.f/16.f,3.f/16.f);
        SpriteList[13].Resize(18.f/16.f,3.f/16.f);
        SpriteList[14].Resize(60.f/16.f,48.f/16.f);
        SpriteList[15].Resize(60.f/16.f,48.f/16.f);
        SpriteList[16].Resize(30.f/16.f,64.f/16.f);
        SpriteList[17].Resize(7.f/16.f,5.f/16.f);
        SpriteList[18].Resize(7.f/16.f,5.f/16.f);
        SpriteList[19].Resize(pPlayer->get_tGuard()/64.f,20.f/64.f);
        SpriteList[20].Resize(14.f/16.f,6.f/16.f);
        SpriteList[21].Resize(18.f/16.f,10.f/16.f);
        SpriteList[22].Resize(15.f/16.f,15.f/16.f);


///////////////////////////////////END RESIZE/SUBRECT!!!////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////DONT TOUCH/////////////////////////////////////////

///////////////////////////////NOW YOU CAN TOUCH//////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////DRAW STARTS///////////////////////////////////////////////
        GameWind.Draw(SpriteList[0]);
        GameWind.Draw(SpriteList[19]);
        GameWind.Draw(SpriteList[1]);
        GameWind.Draw(SpriteList[17]);
        GameWind.Draw(SpriteList[2]);
        GameWind.Draw(SpriteList[18]);
        GameWind.Draw(SpriteList[3]);
        GameWind.Draw(SpriteList[4]);
        GameWind.Draw(SpriteList[5]);
        GameWind.Draw(SpriteList[6]);
        GameWind.Draw(SpriteList[7]);
        GameWind.Draw(SpriteList[8]);
        GameWind.Draw(SpriteList[9]);
        GameWind.Draw(SpriteList[10]);
        GameWind.Draw(SpriteList[11]);
        GameWind.Draw(SpriteList[12]);
        GameWind.Draw(SpriteList[13]);
        GameWind.Draw(SpriteList[14]);
        GameWind.Draw(SpriteList[15]);
}


void GLMcreate()
{
    GLMmodel* World = glmReadOBJ("3Dobject/WorldMap3Dv1.obj");
    glmUnitize(World);
    glmScale(World,1);
}


void GLdraw()
{
    GameWind.SetActive();
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    ////////AMBIENT LIGHT
    GLfloat AmbientColor[] = {0.05f,0.05f,0.2f,1.0f};
    glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT,AmbientColor);
    ////////POSITIONED LIGHT
    GLfloat LightColor0[] = {0.5f,0.5f,0.5f,1.0f};
    GLfloat LightPos0[] = {4.0f,4.0f,0.0f,1.0f};
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_DIFFUSE,LightColor0);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_POSITION,LightPos0);
    ////////DIRECTED LIGHT
    GLfloat LightColor1[] = {0.9f,0.9f,0.6f,1.0f};
    /////Coming from direction (x,y,z)
    GLfloat LightPos1[] = {-1.0f,0.5f,0.5f,0.0f};
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1,GL_DIFFUSE,LightColor1);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1,GL_POSITION,LightPos1);


    ///DRAWING MODELS
}


void GLiniti()
{
    GameWind.PreserveOpenGLStates(true);
    GameWind.ShowMouseCursor(false);

    glClearDepth(1.f);
    glClearColor(0.2f,0.2f,0.8f,1.f);
    /////z buffer
    glEnable(GL_POLYGON_STIPPLE);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);
    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

    glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
    glFrontFace(GL_CW);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);


    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(50.f,(double)800 / (double)600,200.f,0.f);
    glTranslatef(0.f, 0.f, -10.0f);
}


GLuint LoadTexture(sf::Image image)
{
    GLuint Texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &Texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture);
    gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGBA,image.GetWidth(),image.GetHeight(), GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,image.GetPixelsPtr());
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    return Texture;
}

void ITEMdefault()
{
    Blank *BlankSpot=new Blank();
    BlankSpot->ItemCreate(0,0,0,0,0,0,0);

    ///TEST ITEMS

    Weapon *sword=new Weapon();
    sword->ItemCreate(0,0,0,sf::Randomizer::Random(0,5),1,0,sf::Randomizer::Random(1,4));
    Armor *sword2=new Armor();
    sword2->ItemCreate(0,0,0,sf::Randomizer::Random(0,5),2,0,sf::Randomizer::Random(1,4));
    Necklace *sword3=new Necklace();
    sword3->ItemCreate(0,0,0,sf::Randomizer::Random(0,5),3,0,sf::Randomizer::Random(1,4));
    Consume *hppotion=new Consume();
    hppotion->ItemCreate(0,0,0,6,83,0,6);

    DefItemList.push_back(BlankSpot);
    DefItemList.push_back(sword);
    DefItemList.push_back(sword2);
    DefItemList.push_back(sword3);
    DefItemList.push_back(hppotion);
}
```

Comment: oh sorry, glm as in the model loading one by nate robins. i downloaded it from devernay.free.fr

Comment: Placing a camera is like moving all the world around a stationary camera. GL_PROJECTION is kind of the lens of the camera. But you position the "camera" by applying the "inverse placement" of the camera to the modelview matrix.

Comment: glm usually refers to OpenGL Mathematics library (http://glm.g-truc.net/), you may have a confused a few of us with this :)

Comment: i think i stumped everyone again...........

Comment: i just noticed that i used glMatrixMode twice: glMatrixmode(GL_PROJECTION) then in the main loop: glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)

Comment: not sure if thats bad but as far as i know, my whole model is one color: blue. and no lighting is being applied(gonna try moving the object around)

Comment: okay i just finished(well not really) organizing my code. here it is: http://pastebin.com/dft1EJHP but theres one problem, when doing this, all of my SFML sprites will not show(they are just white boxes) they also dont give any errors when loading(as in SFMLcreate()) if anyone knows this problem let me know, it will help :D

Comment: maybe i should ask this in another question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not one certain matrix mode you switch OpenGL too. I explained it already in this post [OpenGL: What is MatrixMode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367361/opengl-what-is-matrixmode/5368013#5368013) , which I'll simple copy here:

---

OpenGL uses several matrices to transform geometry and associated data. Those matrices are:

- Modelview – places object geometry in the global, *unprojected* space
- Proection – projects global coordinates into clip space; you may think of it as kind of a lens
- Texture – adjusts texture coordinates before; mostly used to implement texture projection (i.e. projecting a texture as if it was a slide in a projector)
- Color – adjusts the vertex colors. Seldomly touched at all

All these matrices are used all the time. Since they follow all the same rules OpenGL has only one set of matrix manipulation functions: glPushMatrix, glPopMatrix, glLoadIdentity, glLoadMatrix, glMultMatrix, glTranslate, glRotate, glScale, glOrtho, glFrustum.

glMatrixMode selects on which matrix those operations act upon. Say you wanted to write some C++ namespacing wrapper, it could look like this:

```
namespace OpenGL {
  // A single template class for easy OpenGL matrix mode association
  template<GLenum mat> class Matrix
  {
  public:
    void LoadIdentity() const 
        { glMatrixMode(mat); glLoadIdentity(); }

    void Translate(GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z) const
        { glMatrixMode(mat); glTranslatef(x,y,z); }
    void Translate(GLdouble x, GLdouble y, GLdouble z) const
        { glMatrixMode(mat); glTranslated(x,y,z); }

    void Rotate(GLfloat angle, GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z) const
        { glMatrixMode(mat); glRotatef(angle, x, y, z); }
    void Rotate(GLdouble angle, GLdouble x, GLdouble y, GLdouble z) const
        { glMatrixMode(mat); glRotated(angle, x, y, z); }

    // And all the other matrix manipulation functions
    // using overloading to select proper OpenGL variant depending on
    // function parameters, and all the other C++ whiz.
    // ...
  };

  // 
  const Matrix<GL_MODELVIEW>  Modelview;
  const Matrix<GL_PROJECTION> Projection;
  const Matrix<GL_TEXTURE>    Texture;
  const Matrix<GL_COLOR>      Color;
}
```

Later on in a C++ program you could write then

```
void draw_something()
{
    OpenGL::Projection::LoadIdentity();
    OpenGL::Projection::Frustum(...);

    OpenGL::Modelview::LoadIdentity();
    OpenGL::Modelview::Translate(...);

    // drawing commands
}
```

Unfortunately C++ can't template namespaces, or apply `using` (or `with`) on instances (other languages have this), otherwise I'd had written something like (invalid C++)

```
void draw_something_else()
{
    using namespace OpenGL;

    with(Projection) {    // glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        LoadIdentity();   // glLoadIdentity();
        Frustum(...);     // glFrustum(...);
    }

    with(Modelview) {     // glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        LoadIdentity();   // glLoadIdentity();
        Translate(...);   // glTranslatef(...);
    }

}
```

I think this last snipped of (pseudo-)code makes it clear: glMatrixMode is kind of a `with` statement of OpenGL.

---

**All** the matrices are used during rendering!

Comment: this now makes sense to me, but i still have two more problems. i will update the question with them.

Comment: Well, I don't think anyone will attempt to understand your code as long as it is the unstructured mess it currently is. There is one HUGE function "Create", with several nested loops, etc. You should restructure it. Each of those "blocks" you created belongs into its own function. At the moment this is unmaintainable. BTW: OpenGL is not "initialized", the whole "OpenGL INIT" block makes no sense; OpenGL state is set on demand and changed multiple time throughout rendering a frame.

Comment: alright, ill spend some time fixing it up, its just if i were to make an object from a class in one function i dont know how to use it in other functions

Comment: @Molmasepic: It's not about classes. It's about structuring your code into independent functions. For example you should have a "drawing" function, that get's called from the main loop, as well as individual functions for event processing, object loading and so on. At the moment your code is a unreadable and unmaintainable mess. Only a few 'goto' missing and we'd have a prime example of spaghetti code. Don't worry, you'll learn how to do it better, after all you're seeking for advice, which is a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

You move the camera by using glTranslate().

Comment: so its glTranslate()? or glTranslatef()? im using glTranslatef() for the projection view

Comment: when using glTranslatef() in GL_MODELVIEW, it has no effect, no matter how big i make the values...

Comment: It might help if you post your code. I'm having troubles parsing it with my crystal ball ;)

Comment: glTranslate() is a fixed function call.  Fixed function is deprecated.  Use your own matrices and pass the data to shaders to be rendered!