# Matrix modes when switching projection

Tags: python, opengl

I am seeing this in a lot of places but I don't quite understand it. For example this piece of code:

```
def update_projection(self):
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()

    if self.perspective_mode:
        self.switch_to_perspective_mode()
    else:
        self.switch_to_parallel_mode()
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
```

These questions might seem basic, but I don't understand their work in practice:

1. What exactly is `MatrixMode` here?
2. Why `GL_PROJECTION` before the projection if-clause?
3. Why switch back to `GL_MODELVIEW`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. OpenGL (in the ancient version we are talking about here) provides multiple matrix stacks: ModelView, Projection (and some others). The main difference is that ModelView is applied before the illumination is calculated and projection afterwards. With `glMatrixMode` can be switched on which matrix stack the next commands will operate. Read more about matrix stacks in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367361/opengl-what-is-matrixmode).
2. This is because the two methods (`switch_to_perspective_mode` and `switch_to_parallel_mode`) will set a projection matrix, most probably either a orthographic projection or a perspective projection. Since they should get applied to the projection matrix stack, one has to switch to it beforehand.
3. Most probably because the next commands want to operate on the ModelView matrix.

Answer (score 0):

The most common what we use is MVP which is model-view-projection matrix. In this case there are only 2 matrices though where `GL_MODELVIEW` contains both model and view components.

The idea behind this that:

- Model matrix is responsible of putting a model into the world. A shape is usually positioned around `(0,0,0)` or at least their vertices are and can then be drawn multiple times on multiple places by manipulating model matrix
- View matrix usually presents a position of camera. No matter where models are defined in scene the "player" or observer position depends on how he sees these objects. In most cases `lookAt` procedure is used for this component.
- Projection matrix is what we use to project the objects on the screen. It gives information on what is the field of view for instance (but really depends on what we are using). Most common are using `glOrtho` or `glFrustum`. They usually depend on screen/view size or aspect ratio.

So projection matrix will update very rarely or even never (except the first time). View matrix may change frequently even on every frame if "user" moves. But model matrix will constantly update as in for every model drawn or even more frequently (every part of every model).

So what the code does is:

- Begin modifying projection matrix
- Set it to identity
- Apply one or the other (in `if` statement)
- Begin modifying model-view matrix

All make complete sense here but the last one might be a bit strange to you. Although unclear but I wager the reason is that the program expects it is always modifying model-view matrix. So whenever another matrix mode is selected it is expected that the operation is reverted back to model-view matrix.

The reason for that is (as said) model-view matrix will be updated very many times while projection will not. If no module can say which matrix it is currently updating then before updating model matrix a call to `glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)` should be made. This means that for each model drawn we should call this line just to make sure the correct settings are set. This is a huge redundancy and expecting to have model matrix set as matrix mode gains some performance.